# Variation in spring constant with respect to the length and no. of coils

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, continuum-mechanics

Do the spring constant depend upon the length of the spring? No. of coils? Like what happens to the spring constant if you cut it in the half?

Comment: Instead of cutting the spring in half, imagine what happens if you paint a red dot on the middle. That thought experiment should tell you what happens to the halves above and below the dot.

Comment: Half the length equals double the stiffness generally. As commented above the displacement of the middle is half of the displacement of the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the standard approximation it does not depend on the length but on the number of active windings. As you can find e.g. [here](http://www.engineersedge.com/spring_comp_calc_k.htm), the spring constant $k$ is

$$k=\frac{G d^4}{8 n D^3}$$

whre $d$ is the wire diameter, $D$ the coil diameter, $n$ the number of active coils, and $G$ the [shear modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus). So if you cut it in half $n \rightarrow n/2$ the spring constant doubles $k\rightarrow 2k$. The maximum length decreases of course and you get into the non-linear regime with less displacement.

To calculate spring constants also check out one of many [online spring calculators](http://www.acxesspring.com/spring-calculator.html).